# Group wise count in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, count, grouping

Trying to get groupwise count based on `shipmentId`.

```
SELECT 
    shipment_inventory.shipmentlocation containerNumber, 
    shipment_master.shipmentid shipmentId, 
    shipment_houseinformation.receptaclenumber, 
    shipment_houseinformation.lastbagindicator 
FROM
    imp_breakdownuldtrolleyinfo 
INNER JOIN 
    imp_shipmentverification ON imp_breakdownuldtrolleyinfo.impshipmentverificationid = imp_shipmentverification.impshipmentverificationid 
INNER JOIN 
    shipment_master ON imp_shipmentverification.shipmentid = shipment_master.shipmentid 
INNER JOIN 
    shipment_houseinformation ON shipment_master.shipmentid = shipment_houseinformation.shipmentid 
INNER JOIN 
    shipment_inventory ON shipment_master.shipmentid = shipment_inventory.shipment_id 
WHERE  
    shipment_inventory.shipmentlocation = 'AKE21192SQ' 
    AND shipment_master.shipmenttype = 'MAIL' 
ORDER BY 
    shipment_master.shipmentnumber, 
    shipment_houseinformation.receptaclenumber
```

Current result:

```
containerNumber shipmentId  ReceptacleNumber    LastBagIndicator
----------------------------------------------------------------
AKE21192SQ          151811      001                 0
AKE21192SQ          151811      002                 1
AKE21192SQ          151810      001                 0
AKE21192SQ          151810      002                 0
AKE21192SQ          151810      003                 1
```

Expected result:

```
containerNumber shipmentId  ReceptacleNumber    LastBagIndicator shipmentIdCount
AKE21192SQ          151811      001                 0             2 
AKE21192SQ          151811      002                 1             2
AKE21192SQ          151810      001                 0             3
AKE21192SQ          151810      002                 0             3
AKE21192SQ          151810      003                 1             3
```

Can anybody explain how I can achieve the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `PARTITION BY shipmentId` like following to get the count.

```
SELECT shipment_inventory.shipmentlocation containerNumber, 
       shipment_master.shipmentid shipmentId, 
       shipment_houseinformation.receptaclenumber, 
       shipment_houseinformation.lastbagindicator,
       count(*) over(partition by shipmentId ) as  shipmentIdCount
FROM   imp_breakdownuldtrolleyinfo 
       INNER JOIN imp_shipmentverification 
               ON imp_breakdownuldtrolleyinfo.impshipmentverificationid = 
                  imp_shipmentverification.impshipmentverificationid 
       INNER JOIN shipment_master 
               ON imp_shipmentverification.shipmentid = 
                  shipment_master.shipmentid 
       INNER JOIN shipment_houseinformation 
               ON shipment_master.shipmentid = 
                  shipment_houseinformation.shipmentid 
       INNER JOIN shipment_inventory 
               ON shipment_master.shipmentid = shipment_inventory.shipment_id 
WHERE  shipment_inventory.shipmentlocation = 'AKE21192SQ' 
       AND shipment_master.shipmenttype = 'MAIL' 
ORDER  BY shipment_master.shipmentnumber, 
          shipment_houseinformation.receptaclenumber
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!